# Is it possible to manage two templates on different hosting but with the same database using commen ADMIN Panel in OSCommerce?

Tags: oscommerce

I am new to the OSCommerce, I just want to know that is it possible to have same database in different templates of oscommerce which are hosted on different domains? 
and Can i manage these templates by only one admin panel of OScommerce?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, There are a few addons that can be used for this.  For example check out this addon... http://addons.oscommerce.com/info/1730

If you're new to osCommerce then you should consider having someone install this for you.  I recommend purchasing installation here http://www.oscommerce-solution.com/multi-stores-p-976.html

I am not affiliated with oscommerce-solutions at all but have worked with them several times... Always great service and results.